# Consts still in bundle even though using babel env preset safari >= 7

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have a client that has employees working on older iPads and they can't update their safari versions to 10.x+ so they're stuck w/ safari 9.x.  And I keep getting the following error when I try to load my browser app in Safari 9.x on an iPad:

`SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

I'm using `babel-loader` in my webpack config and I have the following babel options that I'm setting on the loader's `options` property:

```js
{
  presets: [
    [
      "env",
      {
        targets: {
          browsers: ["last 3 versions", "safari >= 8"]
        },
        debug: true
      }
    ],
    // `es2015`,
    `stage-1`
  ],
  retainLines: true,
  plugins: [
    "syntax-jsx",
    "transform-react-jsx",
    "transform-react-display-name",
    "transform-react-require",
    "transform-es2015-destructuring",
    "transform-es2015-parameters",
    "transform-object-rest-spread",
    "transform-class-properties",
    // "check-es2015-constants",
    // "transform-es2015-block-scoping",
    ["transform-runtime", {
      "polyfill": false,
      "regenerator": true
    }]
  ]
}
```

In my console when I do the build, it EVEN SAYS:

```
Using targets:
{
  "chrome": "59",
  "android": "4.4",
  "edge": "13",
  "firefox": "54",
  "ie": "9",
  "ios": "10",
  "safari": "8"
}
```

And:

```
Using plugins:
  check-es2015-constants {"android":"4.4","edge":"13","ie":"9","safari":"8"}
  transform-es2015-block-scoping {"android":"4.4","edge":"13","ie":"9","safari":"8"}
```

But there are STILL `const` declarations (65 to be exact) throughout my bundle.  And no, they aren't all `node_module` imports... Most are my own React component files.

How do I get babel to just replace ALL instances of `const` w/ `var`?

I'm on `webpack` 3.7.1 and `babel-loader` 7.1.2 and `babel-core` 6.26

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using a Webpack alias for this project still: https://github.com/njl07/rx-http-request/issues/15#issue-273561398

Apparently babel transformations aren't applied to aliases for some reason.

Updated to the latest package and all is good now.